Why does the f-statistic change between nested anova's?
My understanding of the p-values in an ANOVA table is that it gives the significance of an additional predictor in a sequence of increasingly larger models. So I would expect the first 2 rows of an ANOVA table run on a model with 2 predictors to be the same as the first 2 rows of an ANOVA table run with the same data and with a 3rd predictor. However R's anova.lm does something different:
+ n <- 10
 + y <- rnorm(n)
 + X <- matrix(rnorm(3*n),ncol=3)
 + anova(lm(y~X[,1] + X[,2]))
 + anova(lm(y~X[,1] + X[,2] + X[,3]))
 +
 Analysis of Variance Table

 Response: y
           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
 X[, 1]     1  0.3082  0.3082  0.1901 0.6760
 X[, 2]     1  3.3563  3.3563  2.0704 0.1934
 Residuals  7 11.3473  1.6210
 > Analysis of Variance Table

 Response: y
           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
 X[, 1]     1  0.3082  0.3082  0.1631 0.7003
 X[, 2]     1  3.3563  3.3563  1.7767 0.2309
 X[, 3]     1  0.0131  0.0131  0.0069 0.9363
 Residuals  6 11.3342  1.8890

Where does the F statistic come from in the 2nd row of the 2nd table? The sum of squares and df is the same as in the first table, so the denominator of the F statistic must be different between the 2 tables. Why would that be, if both are just testing for $\beta_2=0$  in a model containing $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$?

The denominator of the F-statistic is the mean square due to error, which is the residual sum of squares divided by the degrees of freedom for residuals.
In the first table you see:
Residuals  7 11.3473  1.6210

Thus the denominator in the F-statistic is $11.3473/7 \approx 1.6210.$
In the second table you have this:
Residuals  6 11.3342  1.8890

So the denominator is $11.3342/6 \approx 1.8890.$

"The denominator of the F-statistic is the mean square due to error" In the largest model that is passed to anova.lm? So row i of the table isn't testing for the incremental benefit of adding variable x_i to the variables in row i-1 ? Because then it would be using the mean square due to error of row i. Now I'm more confused: the numerator of the f-statistic is the difference in error SS between rows i and i-1, but the denominator is the error SS from row p, the last row? What is that F-stat testing?
